# How to handle webpage pop-up with VBA and Selenium?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, popup

I have a problem with a code that I am developing in VBA. I am trying to access a web page through the Excel macro. This web page is to access a camera connected to my network, due to its brand (Axis), when accessing I have to enter the username and password, and these text boxes appear in a pop-up window. I am using Google Chrome and the Selenium library.

I have no way of finding out their "id" by pressing F12 or by right clicking and pressing "Inspect element" as can be done on the website itself. Finding out their "id" could handle them. It seems that handling pop-up windows is more complicated. I found some information about this, but it didn't help me much.

For now I can open Google Chrome and access the website, but I cannot enter data in this window. I have tried several Selenium functions, such as writing on the active element, but I don't give any results. Any information on this would help me a lot.

These are my few lines of functional code and a image of the pop-up window:

```
Public Sub OpenUrl()

Dim obj As New WebDriver

obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.Get ("webpage")

End Sub
```

[image: The pop-up window]

Comment: I can't remember vba implementation but do you have the equivalent of driver.switch_to.alert  that you can use to focus on that then sendkeys the required info? Python example: https://www.techbeamers.com/handle-alert-popup-selenium-python/

Comment: @QHarr I've tested with obj.SwitchToAlert.SendKeys and obj.SwitchToNextWindow but it appears a error message saying "NoAlertPresentError no such alert..."

Answer (score 0):

Use application.sendkeys to interact with the pop up window box. Use this website to learn more what steps you are able to complete:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31357549)